# tcplistener and client in same Forms app

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I have this code that seems to stop working at `Socket client = listener.AcceptSocket();`

This code works fine in a console app but when I try to use it in a windows forms app it doesn't start / the windows doesn't show up

Here is my code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Listen();
    }
    public void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

            Console.WriteLine("Starting TCP listener...");

            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 1302);

            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server is listening on " + listener.LocalEndpoint);

                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

                Socket client = listener.AcceptSocket(); // <----- PROBLEM

                Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted.");

                Console.WriteLine("Reading data...");

                byte[] data = new byte[100];
                int size = client.Receive(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved data: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(data[i]));

                Console.WriteLine();

                client.Close();
            }

            listener.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.StackTrace);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            textToSend = richTextBox1.Text;
            run = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Box Cant Be Empty");
            run = false;
        }
        if (run)
        {
            try
            {
                TCPclient = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
                nwStream = TCPclient.GetStream();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

            //---send the text---
            MessageBox.Show("Sending : " + textToSend);
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The console will continue to output even when the code that is running is busy. It is painted outside of your application.

The windows form you are using needs the main application thread to be available for it to update and paint the form. You should look up the async / await pattern and learn to use it for blocking IO calls. The topic is too big to give you a simple quick answer, but you can find some information on async / await here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx though there may be better articles to be found with some googlefu.

Some additional information can be found here about UI responsiveness:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Socket client = listener.AcceptSocket();` is waiting for an incoming packet. **Unless and until it receives one, WinForm UI won't show up**, as you are calling `Listen();` in the form constructor, thus blocking the Main Thread(UI).

Run `Listen();` in a separate thread.

Comment: ok ive done that and it worked but how do i change a variable outside that thread? fx. MessageBox.Show();or ListBox1.Items.Add();

Comment: its explained pretty good if i need to change a variable outside of that thread that doesnt work

Comment: Unless you provide an example code, I won't be able to answer that properly as there are multiple ways to do so.

Comment: ok i now have `public void Listen()
    {
        try
        { //The Code}
            }).Start();`